# LispWorks program will not build as application

Tags: common-lisp, lispworks

This is my second proper attempt at a Lisp program, as a dice-roller for Mythender (a freely distributed tabletop RPG). It has a couple of problems though:

- When it's loaded I get a prompt to confirm creation of the package. Surely this file should be creating it?
- When I try to build it standalone with the LispWorks application builder it gives an error saying that I am trying to invoke a CAPI function at compile-time, but I don't see where that is.
- I've gotten negative comments from some lisp folks I spoke to about the (the null ()) sections which are meant to indicate a function has no return so no point leaving anything on the stack - is this proper or not? Is there a better way to do it?

Any general suggestions would also be welcome.

```
(defpackage :mythender (:add-use-defaults t) (:use "CAPI"))
(in-package :mythender)

(defun d6 () (the fixnum (+ 1 (random 6))))

(defun d6s (count)
  (declare (type fixnum count))
  (the list (loop for x from 1 to count collecting (d6))))

(defun d6over (count threshold) 
  (declare (type fixnum count threshold))
  (the fixnum (count-if 
   (lambda (x) (> threshold x)) 
   (d6s count))))

(defvar *storm* 3)
(defvar *thunder* 3)
(defvar *lightning* 0)

(declare (ftype (function) printstate))
(defun printstate ()
  (print *storm*)
  (print *thunder*)
  (print *lightning*)
  (the null ()))

(defun roll () 
  (incf *lightning* (d6over *thunder* 3))
  (incf *thunder* (d6over *storm* 3))
  (the null ()))

(defun damage (threshold)
  (setf *thunder* (d6over *thunder* threshold))
  (the null ()))

(defun doroll (&rest args)
  (roll)
  (update-interface)
  (the null ()))


(define-interface mythender-interface () ()
  (:panes
   (roll-button push-button :data "Roll" :callback #'doroll)
   (damage-button push-button :data "Damage")
   (storm-pane display-pane :title "Storm:" :title-position :left)
   (thunder-pane display-pane :title "Thunder:" :title-position :Left)
   (lightning-pane display-pane :title "Lightning:" :title-position :left))
  (:layouts
   (main-layout column-layout '(storm-pane thunder-pane lightning-pane buttonlayout))
   (buttonlayout row-layout '(roll-button damage-button))))

(defvar *interface*)

(defun update-interface-slot (slotname value)
  (declare (type string slotname) (type fixnum value))
  (setf (display-pane-text (slot-value *interface* slotname)) (write-to-string value))
  (the null ()))

(defun update-interface () 
  (update-interface-slot 'storm-pane *storm*)
  (update-interface-slot 'thunder-pane *thunder*)
  (update-interface-slot 'lightning-pane *lightning*)
  (the null ()))


(defun start () 
  (setf *interface* (make-instance 'mythender-interface))
  (display *interface*)
  (the null (update-interface)))
```

Comment: You better include the build statement and the real error message.

Comment: If you don't want to return any values, use `(values)`.  As it is, you're explicitly returning the symbol `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

An answer to your build problem has to wait until you tell us the build statement and the error message.

Your last question:

```
(declare (ftype (function) printstate))
(defun printstate ()
  (print *storm*)
  (print *thunder*)
  (print *lightning*)
  (the null ()))
```

It's known that it is a function. No need to declare that. Declaring types like that, have in plain Common Lisp only the purpose of optimization hints to the compiler, which the compiler may ignore. Only CMUCL (and derived compilers like SBCL and SCL) actually does more with declared types.

Nobody writes such code in Lisp. Better omit the types. Remember: Lisp is not a statically typed language.

```
(defun printstate ()
  (print *storm*)
  (print *thunder*)
  (print *lightning*)
  (values))
```

Using `(values)` causes the function to not return a value. That's usually preferred, not returning `NIL`.

If you want to actually check types in a meaningful way at runtime, then make use of `ASSERT`, `CHECK-TYPE` and/or `DEFMETHOD`.

```
(defun d6s (count)
  (declare (type fixnum count))
  (the list (loop for x from 1 to count collecting (d6))))
```

Is just:

```
(defmethod d6s ((n integer))
  "Returns a list of n dice rolls."
  (loop repeat n collect (d6)))
```

Don't forget to describe the semantics of your function in human readable form.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add the compile error when I get a chance to try it again. The LispWorks manual does state that performing type declares removes runtime type checking from the compiled application and thus speeds it up, so presumably there is some optimization there. Is there any way to get rid of the "do you really want to create this package?" prompt?